# Equation \frac inside \underbrace has bigger font

Tags: math-mode, mathtools

- in explaining parts of an equation, I group terms in an array and add `\underbrace` explanations to single parts
- the first term within each underbrace is a fraction (`\frac`), but its font is too big when compared to the term without the underbrace part (see picture)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[sf,scale=0.9]{merriweather}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lllll}
-\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x} & +\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_1 & +\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x} & -\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_1 & \\
\underbrace{+\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x}}_{\mathclap{\text{cancel}}} & \underbrace{-\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_2}_{\mathclap{\bm{x}^T \bm{w}\text{,  but without} \frac{1}{2}}} & \underbrace{-\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_2^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x}}_{\mathclap{\text{?}}} & \underbrace{+\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_2^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_2 + \log \frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)}}_{\mathclap{\bm{w}_0}} \\

\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just use `\tfrac`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\underbrace` applies `\displaystyle` unconditionally. Using two arguments seems more in line with the standard syntax. So I provide a command `\ubrace{<math material>}{<subscript>}`. It would be possible to change `\underbrace` itself, but it's better not to.

Here's the code. I add also some improvements to the setting. In particular, I reduce the intercolumn space to 1pt, add empty atoms to provide the right spacing and smash a couple of things to get vertical alignment of the braces and the subscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no longer necessary
\usepackage[largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[sf,scale=0.9]{merriweather}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{\mathord{\mathpalette\ubrace@{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\ubrace@}[2]{\ubrace@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\ubrace@@}[3]{% #1=style, #2=math to be underbraced, #3=subscript
  \underbrace{#1#2}_{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\begin{array}{@{} *{4}{l} @{} }
-\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x} &
  {}+\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_1 &
  {}+\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x} & 
  {}-\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_1
\\[2ex]
  \ubrace{+\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x}}
         {\text{\smash{cancel}}} &
  \ubrace{{}-\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_2}
         {\smash[t]{\mathclap{\bm{x}^T \bm{w}\text{, but without} \frac{1}{2}}}} &
  \ubrace{{}-\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_2^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x}}
         {\text{?}} &
  \ubrace{{}+\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_2^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_2 + 
          \log \smash[b]{\frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)}}}
         {\bm{w}_0}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MarcelKrüger You're right, I'll change the text.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[sf,scale=0.9]{merriweather}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lllll}
-\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x} & +\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_1 & +\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x} & -\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_1 & \\
\underbrace{+\textstyle\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x}}_{\mathclap{\text{cancel}}} & \underbrace{\textstyle-\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_2}_{\mathclap{\bm{x}^T \bm{w}\text{,  but without} \frac{1}{2}}} & \underbrace{\textstyle-\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_2^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x}}_{\mathclap{\text{?}}} & \underbrace{\textstyle+\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_2^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_2 + \log \textstyle\frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)}}_{\mathclap{\bm{w}_0}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would seize the opportunity not only to generate display-style fractions in the second row but in the first row as well, by switching the four `\frac` directives in the first row to `\dfrac`. (If, however, all 8 `\frac{1}{2}` terms *must* employ textstyle rather than displaystyle, simply use `\tfrac` instead of `\frac` in the second row.)

I would also (a) make sure that the underbraces are aligned with each other and (b) increase the vertical separation between the rows with the help of an `\addlinespace` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[largesmallcaps]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[sf,scale=0.9]{merriweather}
\usepackage{booktabs} %   for \addlinespace macro
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
% define 2 typographic struts:
\newcommand\mystruta{\vphantom{\frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)}}}
\newcommand\mystrutb{\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix*}[l]
-\dfrac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x} & 
+\dfrac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_1 & 
+\dfrac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x} & 
-\dfrac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_1^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_1 \\
\addlinespace
\underbrace{+\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x}\mystruta}%
   _{\text{cancel}\mystrutb} & 
\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2} \bm{x}^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_2\mystruta}%
   _{\mathclap{\bm{x}^T\bm{w}\text{,  but without} \frac{1}{2}}} & 
\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_2^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{x}\mystruta}%
   _{\text{?}\mystrutb} & 
\underbrace{+\frac{1}{2} \bm{\mu}_2^T \Sigma^{-1} \bm{\mu}_2 + \log \frac{p(C_1)}{p(C_2)}}%
   _{\mathclap{\bm{w}_0}\mystrutb} 
\end{matrix*}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```